# How can I optimize this method?

Tags: c#

I would like to optimize the following method, that returns the total file count of the specified folder and all subfolders, for speed and memory usage; any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
private int countfiles(string srcdir)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(srcdir);

        //if the source dir doesn't exist, throw an exception
        if (!dir.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException("source dir doesn't exist -> " + srcdir);

        int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;

        //loop through each sub directory in the current dir
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            //recursively call this function over and over again
            count += countfiles(subdir.FullName);
        }

        //cleanup
        dir = null;

        return count;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        return 0;
    }           
}
```

#### So I did some benchmarking with the suggestions that were proposed.  Here are my findings:

- My method, with recursion, is the slowest finding 9062 files in a directory tree in 6.234 seconds.
- @Matthew’s answer, using SearchOption.AllDirectories,  is the fastest finding the same 9062 files in 4.546 seconds
- @Jeffery’s answer, using LINQ, is in the middle of the pack finding the same 9062 files in 5.562 seconds.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: First rule of optimization: have you measured a speed problem or memory bloat in your application? If so, have you traced it to this method? I wouldn't be concerned about optimizing it at all until both of those are true. It's not *obviously* slow, then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not change the entire method to:

```
int count = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

Comment: +1, just note that you can archive the same result by `"*"` instead of "*.*".

Comment: I'm curious, in terms of performance and memory usage does that make much difference? It's fewer lines of code, which is good,  but how much performance difference? I suppose it depends whether GetFiles() is doing anything different from the original hand-rolled loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty good to me, but I'd use a LINQ expression to get the count.

Try this:

```
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length + dir.GetDirectories().Sum(subdir =>countfiles(subdir.FullName));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, you don't need to set dir=null. The garbage collector will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used the approach described here in the past, it shows with and without recursion and the one without is faster. Hope this helps ;-)

[How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If there are exceptions, then your user could end up seeing numerous message boxes as each call could show one. I'd consolidate them, allow the user can cancel the operation, or so that it'd back all the way out to the initial caller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0, this is slightly faster but not by much.

```
static int RecurCount(string source)
{
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source);
        count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(source).Count();

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            count += RecurCount(dir);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return count;
}
```